# get user name from firebase xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to get a user name from firebase and then displayed on a label.
Any help?
heres a sample of the code.

```
import Firebase
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
   
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
                    
  }
   
  func getUserName(_ message:String) {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
       
      if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        self.userName.text = dictionary["firstname"] as? String         
      }
       
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON at `users` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Could only find a json file under realtime database and this is what it says: null

Answer (score 2):

Swift

```
let currentUserName = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName

print(currentUserName)
```

Comment: User need to add "dispalyName", then after above code work.
"createProfileChangeRequest()"

Comment: this is what i have done, and still does not work.                                                    'import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func displayUserName() {
        
    let currentUserName = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName

        self.userName.text = currentUserName!
    }
}'

Answer (score 1):

`user.displayName` It's in the firebase docs

Answer (score 0):

You have To try this code...(After Authentication , You have to create display name ("Firstname + Lastname") inside mobile app using below mentioned code )

```
 if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    let changeRequest = currentUser.createProfileChangeRequest()
    changeRequest.displayName = "Firstname" + "Lastname"
    changeRequest.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("--> firebase user display name error:- ", error)
        }
    })
}
```

After completion of this code we got current user displayname.